# Google USB Driver Unavailable

Tags: android

I'm trying to install the Google USB driver for my device, and I'm unable to. I went to https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml and the page was not found.

I saw several other StackOverflow questions without a good solution.

Where can I get the Google USB driver and how can I install it?

I'm trying to develop using a Nexus S

Comment: What device are you trying to use? I had this and found a different solution but it works for only some devices.

Comment: Might be, or maybe not. But: Why are you telling *us* this? We can't help you here - we don't administer that repo. Also most drivers are available on the websites of many manufacturers, depending on which phone model you have of course. Take a look there as an alternative.

Comment: Please note from the [faq]: [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) **it is a rant disguised as a question: "______ sucks, am I right?"**.

Comment: My device is the Nexus S. As for the "rant", I've asked a very relevant question. However, I'm also expressing my frustration. The question is relevant because it relates **directly** to the operation of the SDK Manager, the administration of the repo notwithstanding.

Comment: Well the answer I was to give was that with our HTC devices they do not run with the Google driver but run when HTC sync is installed. The driver bundled with that works a treat. I was wondering if the same could be applied for you? If/Have you installed the software that came with it?

Comment: No software came with my Nexus S. I found this: http://androiddrivers.net/samsung-android-drivers/download-nexus-s-drivers/. But ADB devices do not show up in the Device Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree it is very frustrating. But if you like developing, it's worth it eventually. And you must remember Android caters to a TON of different hardware devices, Android is Open Source, and it will work eventually. Regarding the question:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

That link will show you the steps to install the Google USB driver. You do it via SDK Manager.

For Equipment manufacturer drivers:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html

I'm guessing you're working on Windows, but in case not, you can reference http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up for help with Mac or Linux.

Alternatively, if you have a WiFi connection, you could install Remote ADB on the device. Your phone will also need to be rooted for Remote ADB, which may be difficult if you can't get an ADB connection in the first place.

If you do need to root the phone, though you can try a google search and probably find a good answer.

**EDIT**:

Also, on my website I have full instructions for installing the Google USB driver with either the **SDK Manager** or manually by downloading the usb driver files. There is a direct download link on my site: http://android.jakar.co/general/usb-drivers/google/google-usb-adb-drivers.html

Comment: I did follow the instructions at your link. Like I said, file not found when I ran SDK Manager. I have a Nexus S, as per the documentation, so there shouldn't be a need for OEM drivers. At any rate, I did manage to find a Samsung driver. I installed it, as per instructions, but it wouldn't show ADB devices. Turns out, you have to plug in the phone **first** before installing the USB driver. Everything now works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. Good luck. :)